# Inconsistent web page load time on Azure

Tags: performance, azure, performance-testing, azure-application-insights

I am troubleshooting a website that is having inconsistent load time. The website is a normal web application connected to an SQL azure database. It is loading the same data and blobs each time it loads.

The website takes around 3 seconds at times, 6-7 seconds at other times, and occasionally even 19 or 44 seconds (data from an Application Insights Availability test, reproduced below).

Does anyone have ideas on what could be the cause and how can I further troubleshoot this problem?

UPDATE: APPService is running on D1 (Shared) and SQL Server is Standard S1

[image: Application Insights Availability Test]

Comment: What's the Performance blade saying about those slow requests in App Insights? You need to enable it first and let it burn in for a day or so to get meaningful insight.

Comment: This could be impacted by any number of things, but it would just be guessing at this point. One thing though: Is this a Web App? And if so, what tier? You *could* be running into an app pool recycle issue. Please edit your question accordingly with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see what constitutes the page load time for a web-test by clicking on any of the green dots that seems out of character. The comments above are correct, there can be a number of factors that would increase the load time. The link below shows how to review errors, but that same process works for non failures as well.

The only caveat here is web-test failures are usually stored on a one-to-one basis--one red dot should have a corresponding failure report--whereas a passing web-test will only save a sample.

Here are some possibilities that could be shown in the web test screen. If none of these appear to be answered by the test results then I would agree with evilSnobu and recommend enabling AppInsights.

1. Initial page load
2. High load volume
3. Third party resource like jQuery or a font package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability